# Getting Super Confused with User associations in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am teaching myself Rails and the project that I am working on is an auction site.  The user can be either the seller or the bidder.  When I tried associations, I can get the seller's information to show up but not the bidder's. I have so much and still can't figure it out.  Any help would be much appreciated.

https://github.com/sgrzona/ebay

```
auction.rb

class Auction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :seller, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :user_id
  has_many :auction_bids
  belongs_to :bidder, class_name: 'User'

auction_bid.rb

class AuctionBid < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bidder, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'bidder_id'
  has_one :seller, :class_name => 'User'
  belongs_to :auction

user.rb

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :auctions
  has_many :auction_bids
```

auction_bids_controller.rb

```
class AuctionBidsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :edit, :update, :create, :destroy]



def my
    @auction_bids = current_user.auction_bids.order("expires_at asc")
  end

  def index
    @auction = Auction.find(params[:auction_id])
    @auction_bids = @auction.auction_bids.order("bid desc")
  end

  def new
    @auction = Auction.find(params[:auction_id])
    @auction_bid = AuctionBid.new
  end

  def show
    @auction_bid = AuctionBid.find(params[:id])
    @auction = @auction_bid.auction
  end

  def create
    @auction = Auction.find(params[:auction_id])
    @auction_bid = @auction.auction_bids.new(auction_bid_params)

    Rails.logger.info "\n\n*** #{@auction_bid.inspect}\n"

    if not_users_own_auction?
      if @auction_bid.save
        redirect_to @auction, :notice => "You are the current high bidder"
      else
        render :new
      end
    else
      flash[:error] = "You cannot bid on your won auction."
      redirect_to @auction
    end
  end

   private

  def auction_bid_params
    params.require(:auction_bid).permit(:bid)
  end

  def not_users_own_auction?
    @auction.seller != current_user
  end
end
```

auctions_controller.rb

```
class AuctionsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :edit, :update, :create, :destroy, :my]
  before_action :set_auction, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy ]



 # GET /auctions
  def index
    @auctions = Auction.all
  end

  def my
    @auctions = current_user.auctions.order("expires_at asc")
    @auction_bids = current_user.auction_bids.order("expires_at asc")
  end

   # GET /auctions/1
  def show
    @auction = Auction.find(params[:id])
  end

  # GET /auctions/new
  def new
    @auction = current_user.auctions.build
  end

  # POST /auctions
  def create  
    @auction = current_user.auctions.build(auction_params)

    if @auction.save
      redirect_to @auction, notice: 'Auction was successfully created.' 
    else
      render action: "new"
    end
  end

  def update
    if @auction.update(auction_params)
      redirect_to @auction, notice: 'Auction was successfully   updated.' 
    else
      render action: 'edit'
    end
  end


  # DELETE /auctions/1
  def destroy
    if @auction.destroy
      redirect_to auctions_url, notice: 'Auction was successfully destroyed.' 
    else
      redirect_to auctions_url, error: 'Auction could not be destroyed.'
    end
  end


  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_auction
      @auction = Auction.find(params[:id])
    end

    def correct_user
      if @auction.seller != current_user
        redirect_to auctions_path, error: "Not authorized to edit this auction" 
      end
    end
    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def auction_params
      params.require(:auction).permit(:title, :description, :user_id, :image, :expires_at)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for associations along the lines of:

```
class Auction < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :seller, class_name: 'User', foreign_key: :user_id
  has_many :auction_bids
  has_many :bidders, :through => :auction_bids

auction_bid.rb

class AuctionBid < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :bidder, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => :bidder_id
  belongs_to :auction

user.rb

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :auctions    , :through => :auction_bids
  has_many :auction_bids, :foreign_key => 'bidder_id'
```

@auction.bidders will be a collection proxy. http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/CollectionProxy. Rails is returning a set of bidder objects to you that you have to iterate over with something like:

```
@auction.bidders.each do |bidder|
  puts bidder.to_s
end
```

Or you can do something like:

```
@auction.bidders.count
```

... to get the number of bidders for example.

Comment: Thanks! Hopefully that helps.  Tried it and then got error messages, hoping that after I fix those, it will work.

Comment: Would I have to define bidder? This is where I am getting an error. I had it @auction.bidder and it said undefined method bidder

Comment: It would be @auction.bidders -- plural

Comment: When I user @auction.bidders  I get this error message  #<User::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x00000004c75c78>